# Парсинг ответа от устройства в понятный вид (rs-485)

Tags: modbus

Имеется устройство, нужно считать из его памяти дату производства. Согласно карте памяти известно следующее:
Адрес параметра: 0х0103
Дата изготовления устройства:
Биты 11-15 – день месяца.
Биты 7-10 – месяц.
Биты 0-6 – год - 2000.
Выполнив запрос по данному адресу я получаю следующей ответ: 6295.
Известно что дата производства устройства (из другой программы): 03.02.2023.
Как преобразовать 6295 в дату?
Как не делал, получаются другие значения, даже после преобразования числа 6295 в в бинарный код "110001010010101" и разбивку на группы получается непонятное значение...
Можете обьяснить как правильно распарсить приведенные данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
6295  0001 1000 1001 0111

0-5   010111 23
6-10  00010   2
11-15 00011   3
```

Что-то один бит не клеится, может тебе поможет.